# Using JDBC DriverManager.getConnection for a web application

Tags: java, jdbc

Our team is planning to migrate to a web application instead of the desktop application. One thing though is for the first round of updates, we are not planning to make any changes to the back-end DB calls. It will mostly be the screen changes that get migrated to React or Angular and deploy it in Tomcat server.

In our desktop application we have used DriverManger.getConnection() class to get the connection from DB.

We plan to not touch the DB interface yet or use modern approaches like Hibernate / JPA or JDBC Templates and just stick with raw JDBC code for now which will be wrapped using Spring boot/Rest API calls.

We have a very small user base, like around 50 people and my lead is not very much interested in using connection pooling and stuff yet though which comes with DataSource interface.

Is it is safe to continue using DriverManager.getConnection() to get connections from DB when you deploy your war file in multiple Tomcat instances? It seems to work though and is doable (tried with single Tomcat instance), other than the fact that we don't use features like connection pooling, etc.

Comment: Not switching over to jpa or whatever is understandable.  But using a pool is a small change that should increase responsiveness and resilency even if you don't have a large number of users

Answer (score 1):

Whether to use a `DataSource` or `DriverManager.getConnection` is not directly related to security. So, yes, you can continue to use `DriverManager.getConnection`, it is just not generally considered a good idea to use in web applications for reasons of scalability.

However, you'll miss out on benefits like:

1. connection pooling (note though that not all `DataSource` implementations provide connection pooling),
2. simplifying connection configuration (though that depends on how and where you're allocating them now); in some case this *could* improve security,

and other potential benefits - depending on the actual data source used - like:

3. identifying and reclaiming connections leaks,
4. limiting the maximum number of connections, etc.

If your current code already centralizes connection configuration, then the first step could simply be injecting (or retrieving with JNDI) a data source (e.g. one configured in Tomcat), and replacing `DriverManager.getConnection(...)` with `dataSource.getConnection()`.

Comment: Thanks Mark .  Little off topic is JNDI still used today especially with regards to applications using Spring Boot

Comment: @dsreddy In my experience, no, not if you're using Spring Boot. If you're using Spring Boot, you generally configure the datasource in `application.yml` or `application.properties`, and you can then auto-wire (inject) it where needed.